# How to center text columns in CSS

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, center

I have quite of a pickle with two text columns, on a small (beginners) project, and friend and I are working on. This is our code.

```
h3 {
text-align: left;
font-family: Times;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}



.AboutBA {
text-align: justify;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
left: 190px;

}

.Position {
text-align: justify;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
left: 650px;
bottom: 319px;
}
```

I don't want to change too much, to not destroy the layout, the only thing I'm looking for is to center the two text columns so they stand below the picture above.

[Here is how the code looks as of now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqcm3.png)

Comment: Could you add the corresponding HTML code of the text columns you want to center?

Comment: it would be helpfull to also see html :)

Comment: make them `inline-block` and use `text-align: center` on the parent https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KvMVyd

Comment: there's also display:table + margin:auto for parent and table-cell for both children ... but HTML is still missing

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .textDiv {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #CDD0E1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: table;
        height:200px;
    }

        .textDiv div {
            float: left;
            width: 35%;
            padding:10px 5% 20px;
            display: inline-table;
        }
  .textDiv div span {
                 text-align: justify;
                  font-size: 13px;
            }
            .textDiv div strong {
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 40px;
                text-align: left !important;
            }
```

```html
<div class="textDiv">
  <div>
     <strong>  teacher empowers kids</strong>
     <br />
     <span>Chris Ulmer, 28, reflects on the decision to leave his teaching career in order to focus on a worldwide mission.
     </span>
  </div>
  <div>
     <strong> How he found his calling</strong>
     <br />
     <span> Ulmer, originally from Philadelphia, attended Penn State where he majored in media effects, or “the way social media affects those who take it in,” he explains.
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

````
    // taget all hr in the sectionk
    var h3Elements = $('section.moreBlogs h3');
    var tallestHeight = 0;
    // get all h3's hegith in the section
    h3Elements.each(function() {
        var height = $(this).height();
        // get the height heigt of h3 and save it
        if (height > tallestHeight) {
            tallestHeight = height;
        }
    });
    // use the height height of h3 to all h3s
    $('section.moreBlogs h3').css('height',tallestHeight)
});
</script>```
````